# how to disable a jQuery variable after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a question about how to eliminate my jQuery function onclick after calling it, it doesn't seem to work BUT after calling it, it must be true and so does it have to be removed follow in the function. Many thanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#try-out").mouseenter(function(){
           $("#try-out").fadeTo("fast",0.9);
                                });
        $("#try-out").mouseleave(function(){
           $("#try-out").fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
                                });
var onclick = function(){

        $("#try-out").click(function(){
                 $(".button-text").fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).text("Downloading... Your account wil be set up whitin seconds!").css(
        {"font-family": "biko",
        "color": "grey",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "padding-top": "3%"}).fadeIn("slow");}
        );
    });
    }
    onclick();

    if (onclick){
    delete onclick;
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. You just need to have the click event enabled once?

Comment: What does "disable a variable" *mean*?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the function after you click or only have it clickable once?

Comment: But if you remove the click event from `#try-out` it'll still have the mouseenter and mouseleave events and it'll still appear to the user like something they can click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to have the click event registered just once for the element.

```
 $("#try-out").one('click', function(){
                 $(".button-text").fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).text("Downloading... Your account wil be set up whitin seconds!").css(
        {"font-family": "biko",
        "color": "grey",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "padding-top": "3%"}).fadeIn("slow");}
        );
    });
```

Remove `onclick` function that you have written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#try-out").mouseenter(function(){
           $("#try-out").fadeTo("fast",0.9);
                                });
        $("#try-out").mouseleave(function(){
           $("#try-out").fadeTo("fast", 0.7);
                                });


        $("#try-out").one('click' ,function(){
                 $(".button-text").fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).text("Downloading... Your account wil be set up whitin seconds!").css(
        {"font-family": "biko",
        "color": "grey",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "padding-top": "3%"}).fadeIn("slow");}
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

use the jquery one method, this will effectively work only for one click:

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$("#try-out").one('click', function(){
  $(".button-text").fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).text("Downloading... Your account wil be set up whitin seconds!").css(
        {"font-family": "biko",
        "color": "grey",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "padding-top": "3%"}).fadeIn("slow");}
        );
});
```